# Does '!A' mean something to perl?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I was trying to pass a command line argument to a perl script. What I wrote was :

```
perl name.pl arg1 !Axxx
```

After I hit enter, it said,

```
A: event not found
```

When I hit the up key, what I see is,

```
perl name.pl arg1 xxx
```

So, I am guessing it has something to do with the '!A'.
I did not get this error with other random strings in place of !Axxx. Does '!A' mean something special to perl? Is there some way to escape it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's actually bash, not perl complaining.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators

If you need to submit `!` as part of the perl command line, use escape characters to tell bash not to interpret the meta character:

```
perl name.pl arg1 \!Axxx
```